# Weird Like Execution in grails

Tags: sql, grails

Am I missing something that I can't get the desired results ?.
For instance: I have 3 products with barcode 12345, 345678,888 and I enter 345...
If I use this:
[image]

I cant get 2 of the three records... What I am loosing that I cant pull them from the DB ?.

Answer (score 0):

The `like(String propertyName, String value)` method accepts a domain class property name as its first argument. You cannot pass it a SQL expression like you're doing. For example: `like('barcode', "%${barCode}%")`

However, you can create a derived property in your domain class, use it to execute the SQL expression, and then use it in a criteria query.

```
class Product {
    ...
    String formattedBarcode

    static mapping = {
        formattedBarcode formula: "to_char(barcode, 'FM BLAH BLAH BLAH')"
    }
}
```

You can then use the `formattedBarcode` like this:

```
criteria.list {
    like('formattedBarcode', "%${barcode}%")
}
```